# azure-iot-edge: How to enable MQTT protocol ingeste in IoT edge ?

Tags: protocols, mqtt

I believe that Azure IoT edge (GA) supports ingesting data from MQTT devices.  Can someone point us as to how to enable MQTT protocol ingester module in IoT edge ? How to configure it? Is there tutorial on the same ?

/Girish BK

Answer (score -1):

if you haven't gotten an answer already, you can find a sample here ->  http://busbyland.com/connect-mqtt-client-to-azure-iot-edge/...   it's not really via a 'module', but rather you can connect an MQTT client directly to IoT Edge and send messages

Comment: Link only answers rapidly become useless when the link breaks

Comment: So, serious question then (not trying to be funny), since I'm not a SO expert..  what's the better thing to do, when the link in question has detailed instructions that (hopefully) answers the OP's question?  doesn't make sense to copy/paste the content into the thread here, as it would even more quickly get out of date (and you loose formatting, loose screenshots, etc)?  What's the best practice here?

Comment: You lay out the broad strokes of the answer here, enough to point to OP in the right direction of what to search for if the link no longer works. Answers can be formatted and a limited number of images included. But link only answers will get you down voted and flagged for deletion every time. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer